# Android Account types missing google

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, google-account

When I go to Settings -> Accounts & sync -> Add account, there isn't the option of google, just skype and corporate. How can I get the google account type option? I have rooted my tablet, and have shell access. I am using Android 2.3 gingerbread on a Pandigital Supernova.

Comment: if you don't have Google account available, it sounds like you do not have the "google products" installed on the device. Like Gmail, Market, Talk, etc.

Comment: I don't. Although I've isntalled the market, but it says I need an account created. But that's my problem. I can't create one.

Comment: You will need other supporting apps in your /system/apps before the tablet will allow you to sign into your Google account.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to install GMail, you can snag the APK by pointing your Android's browser to [DroidLoad](http://gmail.droidload.org/) and downloading it from there.  You should be able to either launch it directly or save it to your SD card and then launch it via navigating to it in a file browser and clicking on it.  There are more detailed instructions on DroidLoad if you problems.

You should probably also install GTalk, as if I'm remembering correctly quite a few other apps rely on it's transport layer for various things.

Comment: I'd use caution when installing apps from 3rd-party websites that you don't absolutely trust.

Comment: Unfortunately if you don't have the market enabled, there is very little alternative.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your table has not been provisioned with "core" Google apps.  Installing them separately from 3rd-party websites will not resolve this issue, since you will need other "system" APKs as well.

Without an exact make and model of your tablet it's impossible to recommend anything. Knowing those, you might be able to find a "gapps" package built for it.  You will need a custom Recovery image, and very likely a custom ROM installed first before you can attempt to flash GApps.

I'd start with Android development sites like [XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/index.php) and [RootzWiki](http://rootzwiki.com/index), and then searching on Google may bring more results.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out where. After trying various "gapps" packages, none of which worked and some of which destroyed the system, I finally found this page: http://www.cesgeekbook.com/2011/12/install-android-market-pandigital.html

That provided some "gapp" apk's and listed in what order they needed to be flashed. No rooting needed, and was a very simple process. Also gave me Full Google Android Market access. Hope that helps somebody as much as it helped me.